# Uncaught ReferenceError: ZG is not defined AEM

Tags: javascript, aem

Im working right now with AEM and I have some problems with JS. I have got many Js which is compiled to one file via AEM and because of this Im getting many problems in places like this :

```
ZG.component.searchresults = (function ($, document) { }
```

whenever I have function like this Im getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ZG is not defined

Is there a way to pack somehow this function or at least write in different way?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the `ZG` namespace is not properly initialised on the AEM page you're looking at. There's a number of reasons this may be happening. From a missing clientlib import in your code to the JS that's responsible for initialising it not being present on your instance at all.

The `ZG` namespace is registered by the [Zen Garden](https://www.cognifide.com/our-technology/zengarden), which is a closed-source product licensed by Cognifide. Clearly some of the JS you have on your AEM instance is dependent on the JS provided by the Zen Garden.

It's difficult to say more without knowing which version of ZG you're using and what exactly you're trying to do. Ask your team about the Zen Garden package and make sure it's properly installed.

If you find yourself unable to resolve it on your own, please use the form at the bottom of the [Zen Garden page on the Cognifide website](https://www.cognifide.com/our-technology/zengarden) to contact the support team.

*Disclosure:* I work for Cognifide, the vendor of the Zen Garden.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of this ZG because even when I will comment all functions in AEM , AEM adding many functions with ZG to minified js without any asking and because of this Im getting many js errors which block my js code.

Comment: @PiotrSikora while you can implement components independent of ZG, your project is likely to have used it as a base. The way a develper works with ZG is by extending the components provided. It's hard to say without insight into the code and the site structure.